# How To Create Date Logic in Mean Stack Based on Input Selection?

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm a full Stack Developer and currently working on back-end (Created models, controllers and routes) and front-end of a MEAN stack web application. I have created an HTML page with multiple select option boxes. 1 select box is for date "This week", "This Month","This Quarter", "Last 6 Months", "Year To Date", "This Year".

I have some data in my MongoDB database, if user select "This Week" option then all those data which are stored in database should be displayed. I have a hard time doing this as I'm new in MEAN stack.

Comment: one thing matters, From which day, your week starts? getting current date and going backward and forward to start and end of week will get current week, similarly for month and year etc.

Comment: Week should be start from Monday.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly getting you, when someone check on ***This Week checkbox***, you wanna get all data from database etc., in this week, so as for year and month. for this you can use following logic

```
var today = new Date();
var startDay = 0; 
var weekStart = new Date(today.getDate() - (7 + today.getDay() - startDay) % 7);
var weekEnd = new Date(today.getDate() + (7 - today.getDay() - startDay) % 7);
```

This is for week, you can take decision for month and year on the basis of month and year. Lemme know if it helps.

Comment: Yes you got me right, Can you show me some example to get on how to get data from MongoDB based on current week selection and display at html?